# How to apply small-caps to a string via XSL FO

Tags: xsl-fo, dita, dita-ot

I am trying to customize the PDF2 plugin in DITA-OT. I want to apply small caps to the string "Chapter" and chapter number that appear at the start of every chapter.

### What I did so far

In my custom plugin, I modified the following the `__chapter__frontmatter__name__container` attribute-set in the **static-content-attr.xsl** file to include `<xsl:attribute name="font-variant">small-caps</xsl:attribute>` :

```
 <xsl:attribute-set name="__chapter__frontmatter__name__container">
    
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">14pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">none</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-before-style">none</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-after-style">none</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-before-width">0pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-after-width">0pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="padding-top">10pt</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-variant">small-caps</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

### Actual Result

small-caps is not applied to the string.

[image]

### Expected Result

[image]

How can I make font-variant work in XSL FO?

**XML Framework** : DITA
**Publishing Engine** : DITA-OT 3.x
**Plugin** : org.dita.pdf2, org.dita.pdf2.fop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is correct (rather, it will be correct in the result tree). See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#font-variant

However, FOP does not support `font-variant`. See https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html#fo-property-font-variant

You may be able to get small caps if you use a small caps-only font. The FOP font page at https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.6/fonts.html notes that OpenType includes small caps but then notes that FOP doesn't support OpenType features.

There are other formatters that do support small caps and that work with the DITA-OT.

Answer (score 1):

See FOP compliance page.

https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html

In this page, `font-variant` is marked as not supported.

> §7.9.8    font-variant    Basic   no  no  no  no  no  no

If `font-variant` is your basic requirement, consider to use commercial based formatter such like Antenna House Formatter.

https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/v70e/ahf-fo11.html

> 7.9.8 font-variant    Basic   yes This property is extended. ☞ font-variant

Answer (score 0):

Use font squirrel or similar and find a whole font that has a complete variant that is CAPS. Latin Modern Roman is common for this as it also has non-CAP Italic and Bold. It may be free but it ay cost you $s and be sure it is licensed for server.

See https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Latin-Modern-Roman for example

Add this font (or set of fonts) and hen you would likely need to customize DITA to output some fo:inline with the appropriate font.